# Repeating lines in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, crystal-reports

I'm working with MySQL connector and C#. Everything was ok until I got to the reporting part. There is no standard way to retrieve the data from MySQL to CrystalReport. So I read in this page that what I have to do is a XML file of a View created in MySQL then retrieve the data for Crystal Report. I dunno if you have done it but I am having problems with this.

When I put the information in the details section or when I group the information, the information is repeated and its driving me crazy. Do you have any idea why?

P.D.
I can't put any code because all is done in the UI of crystal report.

Comment: I dont know much about mysql. But Crystal Reports allows oledb connection & if you have oledb provider for mysql installed, you can connect to mysql. see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, I think it was the mess of working with a XML file and then calling that to the CrytalReport, solution here:

http://writer.zoho.com/public/13706/27397

Use the mysql odbc driver to make a new connection in the database expert inside Crystal Reports.